# ssh passwordless connection with other username

Tags: ssh, connection

I try to configure a passwordless ssh connection from server 1 to server 2.
At server 1 the user is called "user1", at the second server the user is called "user2". Can I make a passwordless ssh connection for this constellation somehow?
Normal ssh-keygen + put the content of the id_rsa.pub in the auhtorized_keys of the other server is not working.
Do someone know a possibility for that?
By the way. It is not possible to add a user called "user2" on server 1.

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or [unix.se]. You should also include a lot more detail about what things you are trying--for instance, include the exact commands that you are running and the outputs which they produce.

Answer (score 0):

You have various options, but the first thing you need to do is put `user1`'s key in the `authorized_keys` file of `user2` on `server2`.  That's basically saying "anyone with this key can claim to be `user2`".  Next you have a couple of options - first, and probably easiest, is to specify the username directly in the ssh command:

```
ssh user2@server2
```

To avoid having to remember that each time, add an entry into your `.ssh/config` file (the file may not exist yet):

```
Host server2
  User user1
```

Then you'll be able to just do `ssh server2`.

Comment: But if I put the public key of user 1 in server 1 in the authorized_keys file of user2 on server 2 and then I try to call ssh user2@server2 I have to enter the password of user2

Comment: The public key of `user1` needs to go in the authorized_keys file of `user2` on `server1`

Comment: I have no user2 on server1, only a user2 on server2

Comment: Sorry, typo in my comment - I updated the answer though.  The public key of user1 needs to go in the authorized_keys file of user2 on server2.

Comment: I tried it, I put the content of the id_rsa.pub of user1 from server1 in the authorized_keys of user2 on server2, but when I try to make a connection like ssh user2@server2 from server1, then I got a pasword prompt.

Comment: Can you run ssh with `-v` to see if it's actually presenting a key?

Comment: When I start ssh session with debug information, then it says:   
- Offering public key: /home/user1/.ssh/is_rsa  
- Authentications that can continue: publickey, gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password  
- Next authentication method: password

Comment: Just to rule out an error in `~/.ssh/config`, do you get the same result with `ssh -v user1@server2`?